# Multilayer neural networks in Python that can work with factor variables

Tags: python, neural-network

I am new to Python and I need to solve classification problem in finance with neural net. There are many factor variables in my data. Could you help me to find out if there are any neural networks with at least two hidden layer that can accept factor variables?

Comment: Can you show some examples of your variables and their domain?

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci For example, type of leasing subject (like a passenger car, a truck, equipment etc) or a district of client's registration.

Comment: If the domain of each of your variables is finite, you can use any classical neural network and one hot encode your inputs.

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci yes, I know abotu that. But I wanted to know if any neural net can process categorical data itself.

Comment: You mean, non-numerical values?

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci yes

Comment: Well, neural network are basically huge matrix multiplicators, in my knowledge, you can't do that with non-numerical values.

Comment: @ThomasSchillaci I got you! Thanks!